# Is there an alternative for visual C++ __declspec (property declaration attribute) in clang and gcc?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang

There is a Microsoft specific extension, which makes it possible to define property getters and setters like this:

```
// declspec_property.cpp
struct S {
   int i;
   void putprop(int j) {
      i = j;
   }

   int getprop() {
      return i;
   }

   __declspec(property(get = getprop, put = putprop)) int the_prop;
};

int main() {
   S s;
   s.the_prop = 5;
   return s.the_prop;
}
```

Is there any way to define property declaration attribute with clang or gcc?
If I search for `__declspec`, all I find is `__declspec(dllexport)`, but I am not looking for that.

Comment: This extension is intended for COM.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

While C++ does not offer support for smart overridable operators (and there are no gcc extensions for that), the language allows you to implement it using it's existing features.
The following example (which does not assume to cover all cases!) shows a possible solution using native C++ 11 or higher.
We could use virtual overrides to override the properties, but that's not how modern smart properties work in other languages such as swift, C# etc, so instead - I'm using lambdas to inject overriding code for setters and getters.

```
// The following is by no means a FULL solution!
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T> 
class Property {
public:
    Property(){}
    operator const T& () const {
        // Call override getter if we have it
        if (getter) return getter();
        return get();
    }
    const T& operator = (const T& other) {
        // Call override setter if we have it
        if (setter) return setter(other);
        return set(other);
    }
    bool operator == (const T& other) const {
        // Static cast makes sure our getter operator is called, so we could use overrides if those are in place
        return static_cast<const T&>(*this) == other;
    }
    // Use this to always get without overrides, useful for use with overriding implementations
    const T& get() const {
        return t;
    } 
    // Use this to always set without overrides, useful for use with overriding implementations
    const T& set(const T& other) {
        return t = other;
    }
    // Assign getter and setter to these properties
    std::function<const T&()> getter;
    std::function<const T&(const T&)> setter;
private:
    T t;
};

// Basic usage, no override
struct Test {
    Property<int> prop;
};

// Override getter and setter
struct TestWithOverride {
    TestWithOverride(){
        prop.setter = [&](const int& other){
            std::cout << "Custom setter called" << std::endl;
            return prop.set(other);
        };
        prop.setter = std::bind(&TestWithOverride::setProp,this,std::placeholders::_1);
        prop.getter = std::bind(&TestWithOverride::getProp,this);
    }
    Property<int> prop;
private:
    const int& getProp() const {
        std::cout << "Custom getter called" << std::endl;
        return prop.get();
    }
    const int& setProp(const int& other){
        std::cout << "Custom setter called" << std::endl;
        return prop.set(other);
    }
};

int main(int,char**){
    Test t;
    TestWithOverride t1;
    t.prop = 1;
    assert(t.prop == 1);
    t1.prop = 1;
    assert(t1.prop == 1);
    /*
    Expected output:
    1. No aborts on assertions
    2. Text:
    Custom setter called
    Custom getter called
    */
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with something like:
`c++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test`
Run:
`./test`

Comment: Thanks @MaximEgorushkin , it worked on clang, fixed it to work in gcc as well and also made the custom code a method for clarity.

Comment: Thank you, overloading copy and ref operators is a great idea. But what if I would like to construct an object in the getter method, and return that one? By overloading operator & I need to return a reference, but I can not reference a temporary.

Comment: @IterAtor You could create another `Property` template and have it work with values instead of references, maybe call it `ValueProperty`, and then do something like: `T get() const` and `operator T() const`. If by value is what you want, you can just do it.

Comment: I tried `operator T() const` but since it is a type conversion operator, It does not work in all cases as intended: http://cpp.sh/2uad2

Comment: @IterAtor `operator T()` does not work automatically, you need to either convert it explicitly or implicitly.  See examples here: http://cpp.sh/2dajb

Comment: It is a pity that there is an overhead by memory :(
(stored functions/value refs)

Comment: @MosheGottlieb I have improved on your answer with property access restriction for read-only or write-only properties at compile time.
Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

### [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) has support

See my example at: https://godbolt.org/z/PobB_3

Although you must turn it on with either `-fdeclspec` or `-fms-extensions`

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772480/portability-of-native-c-properties#answer-43463142)

`__declspec(property(get=..,put=..))` is fully supported by *clang* and that is a carryover from support in *gcc* for this Microsoft language feature.

I use it all the time in *clang*; it is fabulous for encapsulation and refactoring. I helped debug and promote the correct *clang* implementation.

It does a great job optimizing with [array accessor properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/property-cpp?view=vs-2019#remarks).

```
foo[expr0][expr1] = expr2;
```

Where `foo` is

```
__declspec(property(put=foo_set)) foo_t foo[];
foo_t foo_set(T0 expr0, T1 expr1, foo_t expr2) {..}
```

It also works excellently with templated functions, making it ideal for efficient overloading and forward referencing.

```
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename foo_ta = foo_t>
foo_ta foo_set(T0 expr0, T1 expr1, foo_ta expr2) {..}
```

The only *bummer* is that you can't use a modern c++ **custom-attribute** shorthand of:

```
[[msvc::property(put = foo_set)]] foo_t foo[];
```

So I use this *pattern*:

```
[[msvc::property(put = foo_set)]] __declspec(property(put = foo_set))
foo_t foo[];
template<typename T0, typename T1, typename foo_ta = foo_t>
foo_ta foo_set(T0 expr0, T1 expr1, foo_ta expr2) {..}
```

OR

```
template<bool fFwd=true>
bar_t bar_get() {
  // reference any types declared later in your code
  // template mechanics mean they will not be resolved until
  // first **property** use
}
```

*You do not need to use any of the **template** usage or **array accessor** usage I showed above. I only provided that to illustrate **above and beyond** what can be done with **properties** and making use of **overloaded functions**.*

*I control warnings about `[[msvc::...]]` being undefined using `-Wattributes`. With that pattern my code is both ready for the future, and reads cleanly and more consistently.*

Given properties only work on **instances**. The technique to place them on types is to use an empty singleton on a type:

```
struct T {
  static inline struct K {
    ..declare properties on `k` here..
  } k;
  .. whatever you are doing with this `T` type.
};
```

*Now you can access that class/static properties as:*

```
T::k.property ..
```

Comment: As far I can see, GCC does not support (unfortunately) the __declspec(property) attribute and it is unlikely it will support it in the near future.

Answer (score 1):

Moshe Gottlieb's excellent answer can be improved to allow for read-only or write-only properties at compile time with the following code.

```
// Simulate Microsoft-specific extension:
//    __declspec(property(get = getprop, put = putprop)) type propname

template<typename T, bool ReadOnly = false, bool WriteOnly = false>
class Property {
 public:
    Property(){}
    operator const T& () const {
        static_assert(!WriteOnly, "Cannot access write-only property.");
        // Call override getter if we have it
        if (getter) return getter();
        return get();
    }
    const T& operator = (const T& other) {
        static_assert(!ReadOnly, "Cannot set read-only property.");
        // Call override setter if we have it
        if (setter) return setter(other);
        return set(other);
    }
    bool operator == (const T& other) const {
        // Static cast makes sure our getter operator is called, so we could use overrides if those are in place
        return static_cast<const T&>(*this) == other;
    }
    // Use this to always get without overrides, useful for use with overriding implementations
    const T& get() const {
        return t;
    }
    // Use this to always set without overrides, useful for use with overriding implementations
    const T& set(const T& other) {
        return t = other;
    }
    // Assign getter and setter to these properties
    std::function<const T&()> getter;
    std::function<const T&(const T&)> setter;

 private:
    T t;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a caveat to Moshe Gottlieb's answer. While this does work beautifully, it doesn't cover all the cases. In case the object gets serialized and then de-serialized (specifically I tried using this on an object which gets passed to Cuda kernel), the references obviously stop working, and you get a broken object. So it's not completely the same as "__declspec(property(get ..." which works in this case.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34487300)